# Store setting in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, binary-data

I have an app that I am building and I have to save settings for some of the pages. I've decided to save it in mysql in binary data format. I got a lot of checkboxes. So let's say i have this kind of form

```
<form>
<input type="text" value="some text" id="text">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes1">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes2">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes3">
</form>
```

I have 10 pages that have settings page similar to this one. I think that I can write this data into mysql database in the form of binary data. Lets say the first one and the lest one are selected so I write in mysql `101`. What kind of data type to choose `BLOB`, `VARCHAR` or something else?

Comment: I'd suggest different columns for each checkbox value. If a value is worthy of being stored, it probably has a specific purpose and deserves a name more descriptive than `SUBSTR(OptionString, 3, 1)`.

Comment: The value that needs to be stored is only checked or not checked so if there is a bit for that it will be goodenough.

Comment: Sounds good @melanholly - I was just playing Devil's Advocate, just in case :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient way to store bit-wise data is to use integer data types.  In your case, each check box would represent 1 bit of an integer.  For example, if the check boxes were set:

```
checkbox 1 checked
checkbox 2 unchecked
checkbox 3 checked
```

this would represent 5 (1*2^2 + 0*2^1 + 1*2^0).  Use the following types of integers depending on the number of bits that you need to store:

```
tiny int:    8  bits
small int:   16 bits
medium int:  24 bits
int:         32 bits
big int:     64 bits
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html for more info

Comment: So I can convert the data to integer `bindec` and store it that way then I can decode it with `decbin` and then work on it

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table of default settings, then a corresponding table that will store individual user settings. You can use a `bit` or `tinyint` data type to indicate whether an option is turned off/on.

```
settingDefault
settingId  setting    default
1          loadImages 1
2          loadAds    0

settingUser
userId  settingId  value
1       1          0
```

The advantage here is that you only have to store user settings if they're *different* from the defaults.

Comment: That is not an option because I have same setting for all my users. Thank you for your answer.